# Difference in Ubuntu One sync-speed between Natty and other versions?

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-one, 11.04, sync, connection

I was wondering if anyone had had the chance to compare performance between Ubuntu One upload speeds on Natty Narwhal and any other version of Ubuntu? Also, any difference on how well it connects? [don't shoot me for asking ;)]

I am hesitant about upgrading on my regular workstation, but if it improves my user-experience with U1, I might be willing to risk it...

Thanks for all informed opinions :)

bisi

Comment: Why not test it from another machine (could even be a virtual machine)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend you wait until the end of the month. While some performance work is already in the nightlies, the later in the cycle you switch, the more impressed you'll be by the speed improvements that we'll be delivering for Natty.

Having said this, we plan to have everything in place for Alpha 2, in less than a month's time. And by then, I'd recommend you switch; that way you can help us iron out the release :).